# Using Gradle to build a JAR with dependencies

Tags: gradle, executable-jar, uberjar, fatjar

I have a multiproject build and I put a task to build a fat JAR in one of the subprojects. I created the task similar to the one [described in this cookbook](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/Cookbook#Cookbook-Creatingafatjar).

```
jar {
  from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.benmccann.gradle.test.WebServer' }
}
```

Running it results in the following error:

> Cause: You can't change a
> configuration which is not in
> unresolved state!

I'm not sure what this error means. [I also reported this on the Gradle JIRA in case it is a bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRADLE-1361).

Comment: For a complete answer for Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.kts) see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70864141/8583692).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating runnable JAR with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721119/creating-runnable-jar-with-gradle)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar

Answer (score 255, accepted):

I posted [a solution](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1361) in JIRA against Gradle:

```groovy
// Include dependent libraries in archive.
mainClassName = "com.company.application.Main"

jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
  }  

  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

Note that `mainClassName` must appear BEFORE `jar {`.

Comment: I had to modify this to configurations.runtime.collect for my project as I have runtime dependencies as well.

Comment: I had to add `def mainClassName` to make the code work... I was receiving Could not set unknown property 'mainClassName' for root project

Comment: How do you handle file name collisions? Files on the same path in different JARs will be overwritten.

Comment: @waste there is a DuplicatesStrategy in all Copy tasks (which includes Jar / Zip).  `duplicatesStategy='EXCLUDE'` will simply ignore anything that already exists.  I recommend using the `-all` distribution of gradle with sources so you can easily drill into task classes and read their excellent documentation.

Comment: @Ajax But the thing is, that you don't want to ignore those files. They are there for a reason and it may happen that file with the same name would have different meaning for different lib. I've already burned my hands with such setup. If you'd ask me - building a fat jar is never good idea.

Comment: So what's the difference between the code in the answer and the code in the question (except indentation)?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work any more. I use gradle 4.10 and the new `implementation` configuration instead of the now deprecated `compile`. The above code builds me a small jar without the dependencies. When I change it ( `from { configurations.implementation.collect {...} }`), an error occurs saying that resolving configuration 'implementation' directly is not allowed

Comment: is causing stackoverflowexception

Comment: @BastianVoigt `configurations.compileClasspath` will fix all the `implementation`s, but will leave out the `api` dependencies afik. Found here in another answer the solution `runtimeClasspath`. That includes the `api` dependencies too.

Comment: Can you please provide this example in kotlin in addtion to groovy? I have hard time converting that. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the first one doesn't work on Gradle 6, unless I'm doing something wrong. `Could not set unknown property 'mainClassName'`

Comment: In Gradle 6.x instead of declaring 'mainClassName' variable use main class name directly as an attribute value: `attributes "Main-Class": "com.company.application.Main"`

Comment: What i don't like about this solution that all content is exploded in the jar, we get classes/folders/content everywhere. The OneJar solution suggested by @Italo Borssatto is a much neater final jar with all contained jars in a lib folder.

Answer (score 84):

The answer by @felix almost brought me there. I had two issues:

1. With Gradle 1.5, the manifest tag was not recognised inside the fatJar task, so the Main-Class attribute could not directly be set
2. the jar had conflicting external META-INF files.

The following setup resolves this

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'my.project.main',
    )
  }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
  manifest.from jar.manifest
  classifier = 'all'
  from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  } {
    exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
    exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
    exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
  }
  with jar
}
```

To add this to the standard assemble or build task, add:

```
artifacts {
    archives fatJar
}
```

*Edit: thanks to @mjaggard: in recent versions of Gradle, change `configurations.runtime` to `configurations.runtimeClasspath`*

Comment: This also fixed a problem I had where one of my dependency jars was signed. The signature files were put into my jar's META-INF, but the signature no longer matched the content.

Comment: Special thanks for `artifacts`: exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: When you run `gradle fatJar` the runtime dependencies don't seem to be compiled, so they cannot be copied.

Answer (score 66):

If you want the `jar` task to behave normally and also have an additional `fatJar` task, use the following:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

The important part is `with jar`. Without it, the classes of this project are not included.

Comment: Also see the following issue if you are using signed jars to included and run into a problem with signatures: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar

Comment: This works well, except that if I try to modify the manifest file, I get two manifest files.

Comment: Worth noting (as I included in my write-up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25095068/1040915)) that, if you only want the fatJar task, you can simply set `from files({configurations...zipTree(it)}}, sourceSets.main.java)` - or, as appropriate.

Comment: This does not work. The Manifest file is empty with this solution.

Comment: My 2 cents: It is better to set a classifier than to change the name. Put classifier = 'all' instead of baseName = project.name + '-all'. That way you keep the artifact name in compliance with Maven/Nexus policies.

Comment: Add ```group "build"``` and this task will be in ```build``` group (with other tasks, i.e. ```jar``` task.

Comment: I can't find any kind of documentation on the `with jar` keyword, what exactly does it do?

Comment: @PhilippHemmelmayr I found it here https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#with-org.gradle.api.file.CopySpec...- and here https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html. Basically it reuses the from-filter-into stuff.

Answer (score 25):

Since use of **compile** to list dependencies is now deprecated and all should switch to **implementation** the solution to build a Jar with all dependencies should use the example from this website.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example

**Specifically this command:**

```
configurations.runtimeClasspath.findAll { it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { zipTree(it)
```

**Here is full gradle section:**
[1]: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example

```
task uberJar(type: Jar) {
archiveClassifier = 'uber'

from sourceSets.main.output

dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.findAll { it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { zipTree(it) }
}}
```

Comment: voted up for Official Documentation Reference.

Answer (score 10):

This works fine for me.

My Main class:

```
package com.curso.online.gradle;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
        logger.debug("Starting demo");

        String s = "Some Value";

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            System.out.println("Welcome ");
        }

        logger.debug("End of demo");
    }

}
```

And it is the content of my file build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    compile  'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile  'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.curso.online.gradle.Main'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

And I write the following in my console:

```
java -jar ProyectoEclipseTest-all.jar
```

And the output is great:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.curso.online.gradle.Main)
.
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more in
fo.
Welcome
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer from @ben almost works for me except that my dependencies are too big and I got the following error

```
Execution failed for task ':jar'.
> archive contains more than 65535 entries.

  To build this archive, please enable the zip64 extension.
```

To fix this problem, I have to use the following code

```
mainClassName = "com.company.application.Main"

jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
  }  
  zip64 = true
  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To generate a fat JAR with a main executable class, avoiding problems with signed JARs, I suggest [gradle-one-jar plugin](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar). A simple plugin that uses the [One-JAR project](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/).

Easy to use:

```
apply plugin: 'gradle-one-jar'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.rholder:gradle-one-jar:1.0.4'
    }
}

task myjar(type: OneJar) {
    mainClass = 'com.benmccann.gradle.test.WebServer'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on the proposed solution by @blootsvoets, I edited my jar target this way :

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'eu.tib.sre.Main')
    }
    // Include the classpath from the dependencies 
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    // This help solve the issue with jar lunch
    {
    exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
    exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
    exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple sulution

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'cova2.Main'
    } 
    doFirst {
        from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use next script for Gradle 7.3.3. It resolves errors and exceptions that I was faced with when I was trying to implement solutions from this question.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Main-Class": "path.to.main.Application",
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}
```

Comment: Solved the issue I was having with duplication. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**).

#### Method 1 (no need for `application` or other plugins)

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    // OR another notation
    // manifest {
    //     attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    // }
}
```

If you use any external libraries, use below code. Copy library JARs in *libs* sub-directory of where you put your result JAR. Make sure your library JAR files do not contain space in their file name.

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    manifest.attributes["Class-Path"] = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .joinToString(separator = " ") { file ->
            "libs/${file.name}"
        }
}
```

Note that Java requires us to use relative URLs for the `Class-Path` attribute. So, we cannot use the absolute path of Gradle dependencies (which is also prone to being changed and not available on other systems). If you want to use absolute paths, maybe [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47961942/8583692) will work.

Create the JAR with the following command:

```bash
./gradlew jar
```

The result JAR will be created in *build/libs/* directory by default.

#### Method 2: Embedding libraries (if any) in the result JAR (fat or uber JAR)

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    val dependencies = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .map(::zipTree) // OR .map { zipTree(it) }
    from(dependencies)
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Creating the JAR is exactly the same as the previous method.

#### Method 3: Using the [Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) (to create a fat or uber JAR)

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.0.0"
}
// Shadow task depends on Jar task, so these will be reflected for Shadow as well
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "org.example.MainKt"
}
```

Create the JAR with this command:

```bash
./gradlew shadowJar
```

See [Shadow documentations](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/#configuring-the-jar-manifest) for more information about configuring the plugin.

## Running the created JAR

```bash
java -jar my-artifact.jar
```

The above solutions were tested with:

- Java 17
- Gradle 7.1 (which uses Kotlin 1.4.31 for *.kts* build scripts)

See the official [Gradle documentation for creating uber (fat) JARs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example).

For more information about manifests, see [Oracle Java Documentation: Working with Manifest files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

Note that your resource files will be included in the JAR file automatically (assuming they were placed in */src/main/resources/* directory or any custom directory set as resources root in the build file). To access a resource file in your application, use this code (note the `/` at the start of names):

- Kotlin

  ```kotlin
  val vegetables = MyClass::class.java.getResource("/vegetables.txt").readText()
  // Alternative ways:
  // val vegetables = object{}.javaClass.getResource("/vegetables.txt").readText()
  // val vegetables = MyClass::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt").reader().readText()
  // val vegetables = object{}.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt").reader().readText()
  ```
- Java

  ```java
  var stream = MyClass.class.getResource("/vegetables.txt").openStream();
  // OR var stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt");
  var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
  var vegetables = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
  ```

Answer (score 2):

There is gradle plugin shadow jar with seamless setup.

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.0.0"
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

Please check about version compatibilities with your gradle version here:
https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow#latest-test-compatibility

Answer (score 1):

For those who need to build more than one jar from the project.

Create a function in gradle:

```
void jarFactory(Jar jarTask, jarName, mainClass) {
    jarTask.doFirst {
        println 'Build jar ' + jarTask.name + + ' started'
    }

    jarTask.manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class':  mainClass
        )
    }
    jarTask.classifier = 'all'
    jarTask.baseName = jarName
    jarTask.from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    {
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
    jarTask.with jar 
    jarTask.doFirst {
        println 'Build jar ' + jarTask.name + ' ended'
    }
}
```

then call:

```
task makeMyJar(type: Jar) {
    jarFactory(it, 'MyJar', 'org.company.MainClass')
}
```

Works on gradle 5.

Jar will be placed at `./build/libs`.

Answer (score 1):

I use task `shadowJar` by plugin `.
com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0`

Usage just run `./gradlew app::shadowJar`
result file will be at `MyProject/app/build/libs/shadow.jar`

top level `build.gradle` file :

```
 apply plugin: 'kotlin'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0'
    }
}
```

app module level `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.0.0-alpha-4"
    shadow "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.0.0-alpha-4"

    implementation project(":module_remote")
    shadow project(":module_remote")
}

jar {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.MF'
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.github.kolyall.TheApplication',
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
        )
    }
}

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'shadow'
    classifier = ''
    archiveVersion = ''
    mainClassName = 'com.github.kolyall.TheApplication'

    mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Excluding unwanted Manifest entries fixed the MainClass file not found error in a Gradle build jar file.

```
jar{
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.MF'
    from {
      -----
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 6.3, Java library. The code from "jar task" adds the dependencies to the "build/libs/xyz.jar" when running "**gradle build**" task.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's something to keep in mind about this type of solution:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

It works so long as you're using "compile" dependencies. It doesn't work if you're using "implementation" dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try "runtimeClasspath" if "compile" and "implementation" not working.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.example.app"
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're used to ant then you could try the same with Gradle too:

```
task bundlemyjava{
    ant.jar(destfile: "build/cookmyjar.jar"){
        fileset(dir:"path to your source", includes:'**/*.class,*.class', excludes:'if any')
        } 
}
```