# gradle build a Single Jar with externaly dependency as Jar inside it

Tags: gradle, jar, package, build.gradle, external-dependencies

In gradle, when i am trying to build each modules, I need the external dependency also packaged inside Jar as Jar.

*Below is few dependencies listed out:*

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-xml', version:'4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-oxm', version:'3.0.0.RELEASE'
....
    } 
jar {
    manifest{
     attributes 'Main-Class':'com.MyfirstClass'
    }
}
```

At the end, when we tried to view Jar it should contain dependent Jars inside lib as shown below

```
jar tvf build/libs/test.jar
                   META-INF/
                   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
                   lib/
                   lib/spring-integration-xml.4.1.6.jar
                   .....
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Gradle to build a jar with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

```
jar {
    from(configurations.runtime) {
        into 'lib'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.but it doesn't work. Its not collecting external dependency as jar

Comment: Are you sure you did it correctly? I just tested and it works fine. The initial version did stuff all under `lib` but the libs were there. I updated the example in my answer so that only the libs are stored in the `lib` directory and tried it out with your buildfile. Works like a charm.

Comment: then you are still doing it wrongly, as it works fine. ;-) Show what you tried.

Comment: is this distinct from an uber jar or fat jar?

Comment: A far jar has all dependencies unzipped and their files put into the main jar. Whatever OP uses (I guess one of the spring dependencies he mentioned) takes the libs as JARs from the JAR. So yes, this is different. (And I actually dislike both solutions. :-D)