# Error Running SpringBoot Jar using init.d

Tags: java, gradle, jar, spring-boot, init.d

I have a SpringBoot application, for which I use `gradle :myapp:jar` to generate an executable jar. In addition, I also had to use `chmod 755 myapp.jar` to make the jar executable.

This is the gradle code for generating the jar, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4894308/1195527):

springBoot {
    executable = true
}

```
springBoot {
    executable = true
}

jar {
    baseName = 'myapp'
    version = '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "eu.myapp.Application"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

I then create a symlink to init.d, [as described here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-service) in order to use start/stop/status. The command I am executing to create the symlink is this:

```
sudo ln -fs myjar.jar /etc/init.d/myjar
```

After this, I can do:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/myapp start
```

The issue is that when I execute this command, I get the following error:

```
/etc/init.d/myapp: 1: /etc/init.d/myapp: PK: not found
/etc/init.d/myapp: 2: /etc/init.d/myapp�z�H: not found
/etc/init.d/myapp: 3: /etc/init.d/myapp: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Looking it up online, [it appears to be related to a shebang issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45784), which can be fixed by adding `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the file. However, since I'm running a `.jar` generated by `gradle`, **where would I need to add this line? Alternatively, how can I fix the above error?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jar` task won't produce a fully executable jar suitable for launched via init.d. Instead, you need to run the `bootRepackage` task that's provided by Spring Boot's Gradle plugin and you also need to have configured it to produce a fully executable jar. To do so, add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
springBoot {
    executable = true
}
```

Comment: The bootRepackage command did the trick, thanks! Indeed the executable=true part is needed as well; I already had that but forgot to mention it (now updated).

Answer (score 0):

> sudo ln -fs myjar.jar /etc/init.d/myjar

I believe you need to use a full path for your source (i.e, /your/full/path/to/myjar.jar)

Comment: I can confirm that this is not the case, relative paths work fine. Regardless, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to execute your application through command line.

1. When you have `apply plugin:'java'` then the spring looks for bootJar and disables the Jar task by default.
2. Inorder to build the fully executable jar then you can include this code

bootJar {

launchScript()
}

And then clean your build and run bootJar task once. Later navigate to the gradle folder and run

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

This runs your spring-boot app. I think there are many other ways like `java -jar <yourapplication.jar>`. But I follow this way. Hope it helps.