# How to put dependencies in output jar

Tags: java, gradle, jar, dependencies

For instance:

```
//build.gradle
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
}
```

and output jar is:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/jvs/ro-adr/ro $ jar tf build/libs/ro.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ro/
ro/Noko.class
ro/RoFile.class
ro/Http.class
ro/Out.class
ro/Range.class
ro/Range$1.class
ro/JSON.class
ro/Str.class
ro/Kernel.class
ro/noko/
ro/noko/Node.class
ro/noko/Doc.class
ro/Rsp.class
ro/Http$RqErr.class
```

Is there way to add `'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'` to `ro.jar`?
I know jar cli can do that, I hope more simple way to do it.

I also hope to know how to do it in android jar file

Answer (score 0):

As answered Ben McCann in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies)

Just use following configuration

```
// Include dependent libraries in archive.
mainClassName = "com.company.application.Main"

jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
  }  

  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```