# Gradle Project: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics

Tags: java, kotlin, exception, gradle

I'm working on a Java project and within this project I did my first try with Kotlin. I started converting some classes to Kotlin with the JavaToKoltin converter provided in the Intellij Idea. Among others my custom exceptions are now converted to Kotlin. But with this the exception handling does not work correct anymore.
If I throw one of my custom exceptions (e.g. `MyCustomKotlinException.kt`) within the java code, the exception is not catched (see code below).

```
// Example.java
package foo    

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import foo.MyCustomKotlinException;

class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try {
            // Do some stuff
            // if Error
            MyCustomKotlinException e = new MyCustomKotlinException("Error Message");
            throw e;
        } catch (MyCustomKotlinException e) {  // <-- THIS PART IS NEVER REACHED
            // Handle Exception
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); <-- This is catched
        } finally {
            // Finally ...
        }
    }
}
```

So can anyone explain to me why the exception is not catch. `MyCustomKotlinException` is inheriting from Kotlins `RuntimeException`, which is just an alias to `java.lang.RuntimeException`.

```
// MyCustomKotlinException.kt
package foo

class MyCustomKotlinException(err: String) : RuntimeException(err)
```

**Update:**
I split the throw part into 2 lines (instance creation and throwing) and found that the problem is not the throwing. The try block is left after the instance creation. Is anything wrong with my instance creation of this Kotlin class?

**Update2:**
I added a second catch block with `Throwable` and the following Throwable is caught.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
```

**Update3:**
Changed the title to correct error and fixed problem with adding all project files to jar (see answer below).
Adding the Kotlin runtime lib to gradle does not work for me.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve], for example with that kotlin source code.

Comment: @GhostCat is this enough for you?

Comment: It needs to be enough so that people can repro the issue. Looks like now.

Comment: @FreshD I can't reproduce the issue with the code you provided.

Comment: @Christian Yeah you are right. I just tried with this example and it works. But the exception class looks same, but with a different name and also the instance creation in the try catch is same, so no idea why it works just for the example.

Comment: And also instance creation of another custom Kotlin class works fine, so it seems to be a problem with the exception class.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Adding all project files to the jar fixed the problem for me. I added the following line to my `build.gradle`

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes ...
    }
    // This line of code recursively collects and copies all of a project's files
    // and adds them to the JAR itself. One can extend this task, to skip certain
    // files or particular types at will
    from { configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

**Update**: Changed `configurations.compile.collect` to `configurations.compileClasspath.collect` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58624653/3883569) answer below.

Comment: Use ```configurations.compileClasspath``` now instead of ```configurations.compile``` as @simon-o mentioned above.

Comment: Could you, please, give me a step by step of how you generated your project's JAR? I'm having big problems with that

Comment: how do I do this on `build.gradle.kts`?

Comment: @mending3 What happens if you add the above lines into `build.gradle.kts`?

Answer (score 35):

This error is likely due to the fact that the simple jar task doesn’t take all its runtime dependencies.

From [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example), In your `build.gradle.kts` you can either create a "fatJar" task or add that to your jar task:

```
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    // Otherwise you'll get a "No main manifest attribute" error
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MainKt"
    }

    // To avoid the duplicate handling strategy error
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    // To add all of the dependencies
    from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from({
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when I encountered the exception of 【is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set】, I added 【duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE】 and it was fine

Answer (score 25):

You need to configure your project with kotlin.
So in Android Studio:

1. click on Tools => kotlin => Configure kotlin in project
2. Then in dialog check : All module containing kotlin files
3. and select version
4. press ok

Done.

Answer (score 15):

I'm going to say that you're trying to run Kotlin code without the `kotlin-runtime` library

Check which system you're using and add the neccesary jar file. You can verify that this is your issue by packaging your project into a `.jar` file and running it with the [runtime library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-runtime)

Comment: I tried to add the runtime lib to my `build.gradle` (`compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-runtime:$kotlin_version"`), but does not work for me.

Comment: Perfect! it works for me. Add "kotlin-runtime-1.2.71.jar" then rebuild. That error gone. Kotlin works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me too, though `kotlin-runtime` has been deprecated for `kotlin-stdlib`.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the comment. Indeed `compile` is deprecated. However the accepted answer does not work with `implementation`. So I looked up the [java library plugin configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) and `implementation` depends on compileClasspath.

So my solution for now is to add

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes ...
    }
    // This line of code recursively collects and copies all of a project's files
    // and adds them to the JAR itself. One can extend this task, to skip certain
    // files or particular types at will
    from { configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50"
    //...
}
```

I feel like this should be done by the org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm plugin.

<s>Using `compile` instead of `implementation` in the dependencies of the build.gradle file solved it for me.</s>

Comment: `implementation` is newer than `compile`. Should not be used in replacement

Comment: @Kishita Thanks for your comment. You are absolutely right and compile should not be used anymore. I was looking for a better alternative and updated my answer.

Comment: Oh and by the way the reason why you can't use configurations.implementation.collect or configurations.api.collect is that they can not be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, compiling my project with Ant in console. I've edded kotlin-stdlib.jar into classpath and problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a `enableFeaturePreview` in the settings.gradle caused this issue when migrating to Kotlin 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following solved the issue for me:

```
dependencies {
    "kotlinCompilerClasspath"(fileTree("libs/gradle-plugins/kotlin"))
}
```

Here is the content of `libs/gradle-plugins/kotlin`:

```
annotations-13.0.jar
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
gradle-download-task-3.4.3.jar
gson-2.8.5.jar
httpclient-4.5.3.jar
httpcore-4.4.6.jar
kotlin-android-extensions-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-build-common-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-compiler-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-compiler-runner-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-daemon-client-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-gradle-plugin-api-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-gradle-plugin-model-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-reflect-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-runtime-1.2.71.jar
kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-scripting-common-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable-1.3.40.ja
kotlin-scripting-jvm-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-stdlib-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.40.jar
kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.40.jar
kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar
org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin-1.3.40.jar
trove4j-1.0.20181211.jar
```

---

The complete `gradle.build.kts` (offline setup):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(fileTree("libs/gradle-plugins/kotlin"))
    }
}

plugins {
    java
    `java-library`
}

apply(plugin = "kotlin")

version = "2019.06.1"

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "12"
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs("libs/compile")
        dirs("libs/provided")
    }
}

dependencies {
    "kotlinCompilerClasspath"(fileTree("libs/gradle-plugins/kotlin"))
    compileOnly(":javaee-api-8.0")
    api(":kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.40")
    api(":kotlin-stdlib-1.3.40")
    api(":kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.40")
    api(":kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.40")
    api(":gson-2.8.5")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding maven Bom file worked. It does job of downloading and keeping all the kotlin dependencies in sync.

```
imports {
        mavenBom 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:<<KOTLIN_VERSION>>'
    }
```

Refer the official documentation here :
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#other-ways-to-align-versions

Answer (score 0):

For me, upgrading the kotlin version from build.gradle from 1.8.0 to 1.9.22 solved the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just added/edited this line to gradle.properties file and it fixed the issue:
kotlin.stdlib.default.dependency=true