# Kotlin and Unity development error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, kotlin

I use Android Studio and Unity development, the Library packaged into aar file, and then the aar file as a Unity plug-in. When I use Java, no problem, but when using Kotlin, it will throw an exception. Thanks!

Exception:

```
 AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
                                        at com.lsl.plugin.PluginActivity.showToast(PluginActivity.kt)
                                        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
                                        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
                                        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                                        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lsl.aardemo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lsl.aardemo-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.lsl.aardemo-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassL
```

activity

```
class PluginActivity : UnityPlayerActivity() {
fun showToast(msg: String) {
    runOnUiThread {
        Toast.makeText(this@PluginActivity.applicationContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

}

.cs script

```
    public static AndroidTools GetInstance(){
    if (instance == null) {
        lock (syncRoot) {
            if (instance == null) {
                jc = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
                jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");
                instance = new AndroidTools ();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

public void ShowToast(string message){
    jo.Call ("showToast",message);
}
```

aar file:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Project: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197521/gradle-project-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-kotlin-jvm-internal-intrinsics)

Comment: Thanks, I see how to use "Shadow Plugin" !http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You cannot use Kotlin for Unity development.

> JetBrains has no plans to work on Kotlin for .NET at this time.

- from https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-on-net-platform/2142/28

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 9):

It has nothing to do with *JetBrain supporting .NET*. I actually had this problem and solved it by using [GoogleJarResolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver).

### Problem

When you pack your plugin into an AAR files, the dependencies are not packed with it assuming that the consumer (which is usually another Android Studio project and not Unity) will resolve these dependencies. However, as you'd guess, Unity does not do anything regarding resolving dependencies on AAR files, so you've got to do it yourself.

### Solution

Google has a Unity plug-in which actually does that, it downloads the needed files to satisfy the dependencies and adds them to your project.
As the description and instructions on Google Jar Resolver home page is beyond what you exactly need, I just give you the instructions here for that specific issue:

1. Add [GoogleJarResolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) to your Unity project.
2. Create and add a file called `$XDependencies.xml` (where `$X` is the name of your plugin) to your project. This file should contain your Gradle file dependencies in it. Assuming you are only using Kotlin stdlib, the file will look like this: (remember to use correct kotlin version)

   `<dependencies>
     <androidPackages>
       <androidPackage spec="org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlibjdk7:1.2.61" />
     </androidPackages>
   </dependencies>`
3. Resolve the dependencies using GoogleJarResolver by selecting the menu item in Unity which is `Assets -> Play Services Resolver -> Android Resolver -> Resolve`. This will download and add required dependencies to your project. These will live under `Assets/Plugins/Android`.
4. Build and run your application, and see if it works now.

I hope it can resolve the issue you're having just like it fixed mine!

Comment: This solution seems to be correct, but not working for me. Any updates on this?

Comment: @Malv can you specify what exactly doesn't work? Have you been able to add the dependencies using GoogleJarResolver? Are you still getting the same exception as the one mentioned in the question?

Comment: No idea how. But the issue's been fixed for a while.

Comment: @BehnamSattar I'm new to Unity development but I need to create an AAR that will override the default Activity for an Android application. Trying to process MotionEvents and put into Unity using mUnityPlayer.onTouchEvent(). Some of the project was developed in Kotlin. The application using the AAR as a plugin gives the same java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError referring to Lkotlin I'm confused as to adding GoogleJarResolver into the process. Is it added into Unity after I've built the AAR file, or do I include it into the AndroidStudio project where I make the AAR?

Comment: @kralvarado The process I mentioned above is completely separate from creating the AAR file and adding it into your project. What GoogleJarResolver does is fetching and adding dependencies you want. You tell it what dependencies you need (by creating that $XDependencies.xml file) and then run it inside Unity. After it fetches the required dependencies.
So make sure you know which packages your plugin depends on. In my case it was only Kotlin standard libraries. You need to create the xml file based on your plugin dependencies.

Comment: Hi i followed the steps and even though the dependency is resolved, i still get the exception. Has anything changed since this answer was posted?

Answer (score 3):

It is because there is no such class in the apk built by Unity (with **Internal** build system).

You should put Kotlin related **jars** into "Assets\Plugins\Android\" folder.

In General, You can download **kotlin-stdlib.jar** & **kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar** & **kotlin-reflect.jar** form [MVNrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin) or somewhere. (These will depend on the references of your aar)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If your Android Studio version is not 3.0 and your kotlin is a plug-in,you maybe build project one more again.It means that every time you update the kotlin code or clean project,you hava to build the project twice.

Comment: My Android Studio version is 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [External Dependency Manager](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver#android-resolver-usage) for Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do to get a Kotlin library working with Unity:

1. Install [Unity Jar Resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) into your Unity project
2. In your Unity projects Assets folder create some new folders. Create a folder Assets/Plugins/Android/[AndroidLibraryName] For me that was Assets/Plugins/Android/MyAndroidLib. Copy your Android library AAR file to this subfolder. My libraries filename was MyKotlinLib-debug.
3. Inside that folder create another sub-folder called Editor
4. In that Editor folder create a dependencies file named after your library folder name. For me that name was MyKotlinLibDependencies.xml.  Here's what in that file:

```
<dependencies>
  <androidPackages>
    <repositories>
      <repository>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</repository>
    </repositories>
    <androidPackage spec="androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0">
      <androidSdkPackageIds>
        <androidSdkPackageId>extra-google-m2repository</androidSdkPackageId>
      </androidSdkPackageIds>
      <repositories>
        <repository>https://maven.google.com</repository>
      </repositories>
    </androidPackage>
  </androidPackages>
</dependencies>
```

5. In your Unity projects Player Settings -> Player -> Other Settings, I had to set my "Target API Level" to 33.
6. After you have all this in place, you can now use the Unity Jar Resolver plugin you installed in #1 above.  In Unity (2022.3.12f1) select Assets -> External Dependency Manager -> Android Resolver -> Display Libraries.  You should see a dialog appear with content. If the dialog is blank you have something configured wrong. You can close this dialog as I only used this to determine if the Resolver plugin was setup correctly.
7. Now Select Assets -> External Dependency Manager -> Android Resolver -> Resolve.  Another dialog will appear and you should see it downloading a bunch of dependency files. They will be copied to the Android folder you created.

At this point my Kotlin Library worked with Unity. Thanks to [this post](https://dev.to/codemaker2015/create-and-import-a-custom-android-library-in-unity3d-1jh9) for sharing how to get a Java Library working with Unity and thanks to Behnam for pointing me to the Unity Jar Resolver project.