# NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics when using class parameters

Tags: kotlin

I'm a beginner with kotlin and I'm trying to develop an IntelliJ plugin.

I have a class that is initialized in main:

```kotlin
// file moodleapi/MoodleApi.kt
class MoodleApi() {
    val userId get() = "xxx"
}
```

```kotlin
// file TestMain.kt
fun main() {
    val moodleApi = MoodleApi()
}
```

The above code works, but when I add parameters to the class, I get an Exception:

```kotlin
// file moodleapi/MoodleApi.kt
class MoodleApi(val baseUrl: String, val webserviceToken: String) {
    val userId get() = "xxx"
}
```

```kotlin
// file TestMain.kt
fun main() {
    val moodleApi = MoodleApi("xxx", "xxx")
}
```

```kotlin
// Console Output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at me.bennetr.ideamoodlecoderunner.moodleapi.MoodleApi.<init>(MoodleApi.kt)
    at me.bennetr.ideamoodlecoderunner.TestMainKt.main(TestMain.kt:6)
    at me.bennetr.ideamoodlecoderunner.TestMainKt.main(TestMain.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 3 more
```

I run the file with IntelliJs `Run current file` feature.
You can view the full code here:
https://github.com/bennetrr/idea-moodle-coderunner/blob/dev/src/main/kotlin/me/bennetr/ideamoodlecoderunner/TestMain.kt
https://github.com/bennetrr/idea-moodle-coderunner/blob/dev/src/main/kotlin/me/bennetr/ideamoodlecoderunner/moodleapi/MoodleApi.kt

Comment: Seems similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44197521/1847378