# Using Gradle to build a jar with dependencies with Kotlin-DSL

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

There is already an answer to the question: [how to include all the dependencies in a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4894308/5247292) though it's for Groovy

I'm using gradle with `kotlin-dsl` and the code is not compatible. I tried to make it work using a few ways including:

```
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    configurations["compileClasspath"].forEach { file: File ->
        copy {
            from(zipTree(file.absoluteFile))
        }
    }
}
```

Though this doesn't work. So how to include the dependencies using `kotlin-dsl` in gradle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work:

```
tasks.withType<Jar>() {
    configurations["compileClasspath"].forEach { file: File ->
        from(zipTree(file.absoluteFile))
    }
}
```

There's no need in `copy { ... }`, you should call `from` on the JAR task itself.

Note: Gradle does not allow changing the dependencies after they have been resolved. It means that the block above should be executed only after the `dependencies { ... }` are configured.

Comment: I always get the error: `Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':compile' after it has been included in dependency resolution.`

Comment: Do you add dependencies after your code example (or the improved one). Once you've read the dependencies in a configuration, it is resolved and you can't add dependencies.

Comment: @lu.koerfer this was the problem. I had the `dependency` block after this one. Thx.

Comment: @hotkey: Could you please update your solution and point out, that the dependencies block must before the `tasks.withType<Jar>...`. I guess this could be useful to others in the future.

Comment: @guenhter Done.

Comment: @hotkey appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

#### my case

```kotlin
withType<Jar> {
    enabled = true
    isZip64 = true
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    archiveFileName.set("$project.jar")

    from(sourceSets.main.get().output)
    dependsOn(configurations.compileClasspath)
    from({
        configurations.compileClasspath.get().filter {
            it.name.endsWith("jar")
        }.map { zipTree(it) }
    }) {
        exclude("META-INF/*.RSA", "META-INF/*.SF", "META-INF/*.DSA")
    }
}
```