# Gradle Uber (Fat) Jar and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Runtime

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle, uberjar

I am trying to create a UberJar file with Gradle.

To build and run the jar file I execute commands

`./gradlew clean build 
java -jar build/libs/jLocalCoin-0.2.jar`

And I get Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/primitives/Longs
    // ... rest of stacktrace
    at im.djm.zMain.Main03.main(Main03.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.primitives.Longs
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

I don't understand what is the reason for the exception?
I do understand that Guava library is not part of the jar, but why?

In this [questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies/22640847), in the accepted answer, the jar file is created in the same way as I try to do.

This is `build.grade` file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'im.djm.zMain.Main03'

archivesBaseName = 'jLocalCoin'
version = "0.2"

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.0-jre'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.8.0'
}

jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
  }  

  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jar you created probably does not have guava in it. `NoClassDefFoundError` occurs when your project does not have required runtime dependecies in the classpath. The tutorial I checked created fatJar this way,

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
   baseName = project.name + '-all'
   manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'com.mkyong.DateUtils'
    }
   from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : 
    zipTree(it) } 
    }
   with jar
}
```

and change `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.0-jre'` to `compile 'com.google.guava:guava:24.0-jre'` then it does include guava in the generated jar

and run command `gradle fatJar`

source = https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/

Comment: I've just tried this solution. I got the same error.

Comment: @djm.im Can you check if the jar generated includes guava.

Comment: @djm.im And are you using jdk8.

Comment: No, it's not included. Thet is the reason for NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Yes, it Java 8.

Comment: @djm.im if you change  `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.0-jre'` to `compile 'com.google.guava:guava:24.0-jre'` it does include guava in the generated jar.

Comment: In some topics they say compile is deprecated use api or implementation instead. But in guava github page it is written with compile type dependency https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild

Comment: That is it! Can you add to the answer, to mark it as the solution.