# Spring Boot 'bootJar' task does not build fat jar, instead excludes .original

Tags: spring-boot

```
bubbleshadow% ls -l build/libs
total 83544
-rw-r--r--  1 dlynch  staff  42772394 May 14 08:37 bubbleshadow-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

When running the above .jar file (which is supposed to be a fat jar), I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path res
ource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

I have attempted to follow instructions from: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/

In 8.1 it says *Reacting* (sic) to the Java Plugin:

And then:

Creates a BootJar task named bootJar that will create an *executable* (sic), fat jar for the project.

My build runs within IntelliJ IDEA but not when executing on the command line.

According to Josh Long's Book Learning Spring Boot 2.0 - *Second Edition*, see it says:

```
If we peek at the output, we'll find the original JAR file (non-FAT) along with the rebundled one containing our application code as well as the third-party dependencies, as shown here: $ ls build/libs
learning-spring-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
learning-spring-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
```

Turnquist, Greg L.. Learning Spring Boot 2.0 - Second Edition: Simplify the development of lightning fast applications based on microservices and reactive programming (Kindle Locations 664-*667* (**sic**)). Packt Publishing. Kindle Edition.

I don't understand why the .original jar is not being produced and the jar that it is producing for me is un-runnable.

Comment: I think both of the books that you have referenced are for Spring Boot 1.5, whereas you're using Spring Boot 2.0. Are you using Java 9 by any chance? It'd would also improve your question if you listed the contents of the jar that has been built. It's not clear why you think it isn't a fat jar.

Comment: try to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232334/1063509