# Gradle - FatJar - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, gradle, fatjar

I know that question was asked a lot and has many answers, but i still get it and I don't understand why...

I am trying to generate a `.jar` from a projet with dependencies with gradle.

I have a class `src/main/java/Launcher.java`, in which I have my `main` method.

there is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
mainClassName = 'Launcher'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.1'
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-core:3.4.0'
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-web:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
    compile "com.auth0:java-jwt:3.1.0"
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": mainClassName
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

I use `$>gradle assemble` to generate my jar
then `$>java -jar path/to/my/.jar`
And i get the error "could not find or load main class Launcher"...

I dont understand why, when I look in the .jar, I have Launcher class and in META-INF I have my manifest

[image: screenshot]

Sorry for still asking this question in 2018 but i'm loosing my mind trying to figure out what's wrong. I hope somone will have the answer !

Comment: You said you are using "assemble" to make the jar. What about "build"?

Comment: From what I read online, assemble seemed to be enough for what I needed

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I reproduced your issue locally.

Just add `exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'` to the jar task.

This will exclude the signatures of interfering dependencies.

Example:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": mainClassName
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

Comment: @Hadrien: Make sure your app really works as expected. Bouncycastle is a crypto provider which requires a signature, therefore removing the signature makes all code parts fail which depend on the BouncyCastle JCE.

Comment: After a long time searching, this also solved it for me, thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: Wow, can't believe the message is non informative and that there are no tools, which could lead to point this out. Have spent a whole day on looking on related questions, then found this only by accident. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain this sentence a little more _"This will exclude the signatures of interfering dependencies."_  ?  What is interfering dependency? What's wrong with them ?

Comment: OMG, I spent so much time on this! thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: In my case, `exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'` was sufficient

Answer (score 14):

You are running into the one major problem when building a FAT JAR:

One of your source JARs is signed and merging it into one fat jar destroys the signature.

It looks like Java recognizes that there are unsigned classes and ignores everything but the signed classes. As all classes that do not belong to the signed library are unsigned (like your `Launcher` class) they are ignored and therefore can't be loaded.

In your case it looks like that the dependency `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.55` of `com.auth0:java-jwt:3.1.0` is the signed jar file. Because my sample project correctly executes `Launcher` when I uncomment this dependency.

Bouncy castle is a crypto provider that requires a valid signature otherwise it will not run from my experience. Therefore it is impossible to create a fat jar for your project that just contains all classes.

You can try to create a fat jar with everything except Bouncycastle and ship Bouncycastle JAR seperatly.

Or a fat jar that contains all the required JAR files inside (JAR inside JAR) and that uses a special class loader that is able to load classes from within such a JAR inside a JAR. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33420518/150978

Comment: Thank you for the explainations, the problem got solved

Answer (score 1):

Try to exclude .SF .DSA .RSA files, example below, Nipun

Hope this works out for you

```
task customFatJar(type: Jar) {
  baseName = 'XXXXX'
  from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
  }
  with jar

  exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
  exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
  exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"

  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.nipun.MyMainClass'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
```

Fixed my issue.