# log4j runtime NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android-studio, log4j

I am using log4j in android jar module. I can build the jar file successfully and run it in AndroidStudio successfully.

My gradle config is:

```
implementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
```

But when I try the jar file from command line:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

I got below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at com.yeetor.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Why it can run in AndroidStudio but not work from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies) SO, to generate one jar file include dependency. the dependency should be included using "compile" but not "implementation", then you will get a bigger Jar file include all dependency. Usually gradle will not include dependency in Jar file but generate all each dependency as a single jar file.