# `implementation` instead `compile` for `fileTree` interferes with copy libraries task

Tags: gradle

I'm migrating a project to Gradle.

I have some local deps which are imported via `compile fileTree(dir: "libs/$it", include: '*.jar')`

However `compile` is deprecated.

But if I change it to `implementation`

then my task will copy nothing (except the files which are decleared with `runtime`):

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "$buildDir/output/lib"
}
```

changing `configurations.runtime` to `.compile` or `implementation` doesn't help

What's going on?

Comment: Somewhat related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation on the Gradle Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) shows that the configuration `runtime` has been deprecated. It is superseded by the `runtimeOnly` configuration, which, like the name says, only provides runtime dependencies. There is however another configuration called `runtimeClasspath` that extends the configurations `runtimeOnly`, `runtime` and `implementation`.

So just replace the configuration in your example:

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    into "$buildDir/output/lib"
}
```

Comment: Be careful with `runtimeClasspath`. It is transitive by default and you can end up with a lot more libraries than you've expected. If you have his problem, use `configurations.runtimeClasspath { transitive = false }`.

Comment: You are right, but using `configurations.runtimeClasspath { transitive = false }` inside the task is dangerous, too, as it will fully disable transitivity for the configuration (not only for the task). There may be other tasks or plugins relying on the default behavior. If required, transitivity should be disabled at the start of the build script directly in a `configurations` closure to make it clear for everyone.