# How to run my Gradle Project as a JAR from terminal

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar

I have a GRADLE application which has the following structure:

[image: my project structure]

It has some dependencies as well (can see it from the image above)
I have built it using ./gradlew clean build

I am trying to run the following from the terminal `java -jar build/libs/script-application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` which is throwing `no main manifest attribute, in script-application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I have the following in build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'Application'
        )
    }
}
group 'ScriptApplication'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.9.3'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'

}
```

**Please help**. How can I run the jar from terminal? The next step is to run the jar from a remote server.

**Edit:**
Followed the suggestion from the comment and updated my build.gradle. But I still don't understand where will the jar get generated and how will I run the jar?

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'ScriptApplication'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.9.3'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'

}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Application'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

Comment: See in example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Gradle to build a jar with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies)

Comment: The jar is getting created in the build directory. But I am getting the same manifest error on running the jar. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Application'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

Then run `gradle clean` and `gradle fatJar`.

Then one can run the jar by:
`java -jar build/libs/<application>.jar`

Comment: This looks basically like the `application` Gradle plugin: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html