# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity on HttpPost

Tags: java, java-8, httpresponse, minecraft, httpentity

I'm working with java 8

I'm trying to do a HTTP POST request with a JSON body and then get the response as a string so I'll be able to parse it as Gson (JsonObject)

But !

When i use the `HttpEntity` or the `BasicResponseHandler`, i'm faced with this error : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity`

Here's the gradle dependency that i have
`compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.13'`

And here's the code of my Post request :

```java
private static JsonObject execPostRequestTest(URL url, String jsonString) {

        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonString, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url.toString());
        request.setEntity(stringEntity);

        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);

            String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(httpResponse);

            return new JsonParser().parse(responseString).getAsJsonObject();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it !

Here's the solution (and the reason why it occured)

To run my program, I had to pack it into a jar and when I packed into a jar, dependencies were not included.

Then I had to edit my build.gradle

First, I added the gradle plugins "application" like this :

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id 'application'
}
```

Then I found a code snippet on StackOverflow that downloads all denpendencies and include them into the jar : [Link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies/4894308#4894308)

Hope it can help people that had the same issue !

Happy function writing !