# Sending HTTP requests in a Minecraft Mod

Tags: java, http, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am developing a Fabric Minecraft mod that will send http requests.

Here is the code I used:

```java
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

import java.io.IOException;

public class NetworkUtils {
    public static void post(String url, JsonObject json) throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        httpClient.execute(request);
        httpClient.close();
    }
}
```

It worked well when I run it in the development environment. However, when I build it into a jar file and put it in the `mods` folder of an actual server, it produce the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity
```

How can I fix it? Thank you so much if you can help

Comment: Does my answer help you to fix your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34413/10952503) question contains multiple informations about why you get this error.

When you are in development environment, it's your IDE that run it. So, it will also run all dependencies.

When you build the jar, you don't export dependency.

**To do it, you can**:

- For **maven**, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1729054/10952503) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/10952503) question:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>LibName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope> <!-- here you have to set compile -->
</dependency>
```

With this part too:

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>...</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

- For **gradle**, check [this thread](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-dependencies-in-jar/19571) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4871656/10952503) :

```
configurations {
    // configuration that holds jars to include in the jar
    extraLibs
}

dependencies {
    extraLibs 'my.lib:LibName:1.0.0'
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.extraLibs.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

- You can **load external jar** from your own such as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60764/10952503) :

```java
File file = new File("mylib.jar");
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();

URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(classLoader, url);
```

- If you are **not using one of them**, it depend. Sometimes you have an option directly when you export your jar.