# Gradle Jar Dependency Error

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a java program that I use Gradle to build. In this program I use the JSON jar "org.json:json:2014113" this program compiles and works just fine when I run it in my IDE (IntelliJ 14) It also compiles and runs just fine when I run the jar, except for when the function that I use the JSON in is called, I then get a `Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray` error here is my build.gradle script

```
version 'UR'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20141113'

}

jar {

    destinationDir = file("C:\\Users\\Jonah\\Documents\\Software\\RapIDE Builds")

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'frames.MainFrame'
    }

}
```

and here is my JSON class

```
package logic;

import frames.MainFrame;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONparser extends MainFrame
{

    public static String SLrtrn;

    public static void parseJSON(String JSONinput)
    {

        final JSONArray JSONrtrn = new JSONArray(JSONinput);

        rhymeList.removeAllElements();

        for (int i = 0; i < JSONrtrn.length(); ++i)
        {
            JSONObject parsedObj = (JSONObject) JSONrtrn.get(i);
            SLrtrn = parsedObj.get("word").toString();

            rhymeList.addElement(SLrtrn);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in the build.gradle script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Gradle script is fine but when you run the JAR, you have not included the org.json jar on the *classpath*.

If you don't want to have to do this, you can create what is called a fat jar which bundles the org.json JAR inside your JAR. Such a process is described [here](http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/).

There are many other ways to do this (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445825/gradle-how-do-i-build-a-jar-with-a-lib-dir-with-other-jars-in-it) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies))so you should research the different options but at the end of the day the org.json JAR needs to be present when you compile, but also when you run the program. At the minute you are only fulfilling the first of those requirements.

Comment: I'll give the fat jar a go and let you know if I get it working. :)