# How to create, using Gradle, a standalone self-executing jar file?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to implement in Java a `protoc` plugin. This requires a standalone self-executing jar since a `CLASSPATH` can't be passed to `protoc`.

I've found many articles talking about how to create a self-executing jar (eg http://en.newinstance.it/2012/04/17/self-executing-jar-files/). None, though, take into account the bundling of the dependencies along with the self-executing jar. This means that the self-executing jar isn't standalone. How can this be done?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3445825/1531971

Comment: Yes, that's related but insufficient. The problem is that a jar can't have a `CLASSPATH` that references jars inside itself.

Comment: Oh, right. That is ringing some bells. Being a Gradle wrangler is thankless.

Comment: @VinceEmigh, from what I understand from https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/, Community Wiki wouldn't provide the advantages you claim it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was copied from an existing project and may use some things not included in the snippet (eg Nebula plugins):

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

mainClassName = 'com.example.Main'

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.Main'
  }
}

publishing {
  publications {
    nebulaIvy(IvyPublication) {
      artifact(tasks.findByName('createJarExe').outputs.getFiles().getSingleFile()) {
        classifier '_-jdk8'
        extension 'exe'
        type 'exe'
      }
    }
  }
}

task createJarExe(dependsOn: installShadowDist) {
  final outputFile = file("${buildDir}/install/${project.name}-shadow/bin/${project.name}-${project.version}.exe")

  doLast {
    outputFile.text = '#!/bin/bash\n'
    outputFile.append('exec java -jar "$0" "$@"')
    outputFile.append(inputs.files.first().readBytes())
    outputFile.setExecutable(true)
  }

  inputs.files "${tasks.findByName('installShadowDist').outputs.getFiles().getSingleFile()}/lib/${project.name}-${project.version}-all.jar"
  outputs.file outputFile
  doFirst {
    mkdir outputFile.getParent()
  }
}

// wire the dependencies
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
  if (task.name == 'publishNebulaIvyPublicationToDistIvyRepository') {
    task.dependsOn('createJarExe')
  }
}
```

Notes:

- `com.github.johnrengelman.shadow` is used to create the uber-jar.
- `com.example.Main` is the Java entry point for execution.
- Specifying the `classifier` is more for the `protoc` Gradle plugin (which includes the OS in the `classifier` by default) and isn't strictly needed. Clients of the published `protoc` plugin must use versions `0.8.3` or higher of the `protoc` Gradle plugin which supports overriding the `classifier`.
- `createJarExe` uses the uber-jar and follows the post on [self-executing JAR](https://web.archive.org/web/20171003035528/http://en.newinstance.it/2012/04/17/self-executing-jar-files/) files
- `wire the dependencies` ensures that the uber-jar is created before distribution