# Gradle Jar packaging Vue into Spark

Tags: gradle, vue.js, packaging, spark-framework

I am bundling a Vue UI with a Spark Java backend. 
Both modules are built independently, which works fine with the following structure:

```
  project
  +-- backend
  |   +-- src
  |   |   +-- main
  |   |       +-- resources
  |   |           +-- public <= Where the jar is picking the static files
  |   +-- build
  |       +-- libs <= Gradle Jar output
  +-- ui
      +-- dist <= Vue build output
```

On the backend, Gradle is bundling `backend/src/main/resources/public` into the Jar `/public`. Hence I copied from `ui/dist` into `backend/src/main/resources/public` as a `jar` task dependency.

```
  task copyUI(type: Copy) {
      from( '../ui/dist')
      into( 'src/main/resources/public')
  }

  jar.dependsOn( copyUI)
```

Gradle is copying the files but **after** creating the jar.
In other words, I have to create the jar twice to get it right.

**How can I instruct Gradle to wait the copy completion before packaging /public**

My `build.gradle` jar section looks like this

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'tld.domain.MainClass'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I can think of is to add cp task to copy all the files in the `ui/dist` folder into `backend/src/main/resources` folder, do you have any sample project to play with it?

Comment: @chenrui I did that but the result was somewhat random as if the jar was triggering the copy but not waiting for its completion

Comment: you can have task dependency to ensuring the ordering.

Comment: @chenrui This is precisely what I tried. Can you please provide a response with an example?

Answer (score 4):

While what you are doing seems logical (and bug-free) to me, I don't see a reason for gradle to not wait until copying is done. May I suggest doing it little differently though.

You can directly instruct `jar` task to load files from `../ui/dist` in the `from` block. This way, you won't have to actually copy anything to `public` dir.

```
jar {
    // ...
    from( '../ui/dist')
}
```

This is better as `public` can stay clean of generated code (via build of ui project) and you save time of copying (and potentially issue arising because of it).

and finally make `jar` task `dependsOn` you UI project's build task, so that latest dist is available in `../ui/dist`

Comment: Almost. All resources end up in the jar root directory. Can I specify a 'to' for this specific file set?

Comment: Did you try [`into`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar.html#org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar:into(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Something like `jar { into('...') { from '....'  }}`, notice the `from` inside the `into`'s block. may be see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9359588/469414) answer